# GAE+ Picasa heavy use. Restrictions or quotes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, picasa

I suppose it can be offtopic, but I didn't find this info anywhere.
I am going to build a GAE app that will heavily work with Picasa as an image hosting. It will add new images, fetch existing, update them, work with comments etc. I have read Picasa API docs and I think it can be integrated and used with GAE quite quickly, easily and conveniently. So, is that a right choice for a highloaded web app? What a restrictions or quotes for using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read this blog article:
http://www.carlosble.com/?p=719
Long story short, the guy wasted 15 grand because he did not do his research and found out GAE was not appropriate for this needs.

It sounds like your app might hit the quotas imposed by GAE, I guess it would depend on how popular your app is.  Here are the quotas
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

I dont know of any service that it is similar to GAE and is free to start out with. You just need to make sure this is the right technology if you plan to invest heavily in it.

Comment: Perfect article and discussion below it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you must be aware of the url fetch quota, decide if it fits your needs:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#UrlFetch

I've been recently working on a GAE project that had to perform many requests to the youtube API. Even though everything worked smoothly on my local dev server, when it was running on GAE I encountered sporadic 403 error codes when trying to fetch data from youtube.

Apparently google throttle ips that issue lots of requests at high volume peak times ( http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=1239 )

My solution was to make most of the youtube API calls from the client side (ajax), this way I bypassed both the quota limit and the errors.